# Does fascial interposition significantly improve vasectomy success when mucosal cautery is the method of vas occlusion?

Tags: surgery, sex

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC406425:

> Fascial interposition significantly improves vasectomy success when ligation and excision is the method of vas occlusion. A limitation of this study is that the correlation between postvasectomy sperm concentrations and risk of pregnancy is not well quantified.

Does fascial interposition significantly improve vasectomy success (i.e., azoospermia and no recanalization) when mucosal cautery is the method of vas occlusion?

Comment: Are you looking for a study that your cited source quotes as being an area of future research?

Comment: @Thomas The paper was published in 2004, and mucosal cautery is different from  ligation and excision.

Comment: While the year of publication probably does not really apply to my question, I assume that cautery being different from ligation and excision means "No". Have you searched for studies on your question? Your question seems very specific and, if you have searched for studies and not found anything it may be that there is not data on this.

Comment: @Thomas I found https://www.auanet.org/documents/education/clinical-guidance/Vasectomy.pdf, which is inconclusive on that matter but was published almost 10 years ago so I'm hoping some more recent and more rigorous studies have been published since then.

Comment: Feel free to include that with your question. If you've searched thoroughly, it may be that there is no newer thing to find, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.auanet.org/documents/education/clinical-guidance/Vasectomy.pdf as the table comparing some occlusion techniques with and without fascial interposition (FI):

[image]

Compare the row #2 (without FI) against the rows #1 (with FI) and #3 (with FI): the use of FI seems to have decreased the upper bound of the failure rate. Note that the study was published almost 10 years ago so I'm hoping some more recent and more rigorous studies have been published since then.